# Reducing Execution time of UrlFetch in google AppScripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a spreadsheet which contains a list of URLs.
I am trying to search if an URL contains a particular class or not and based on response I will set 0 or 1 in the cell next to it.
I have made a script and it does the purpose but I'm experiencing execution timeout error so just want to is there any way I can reduce it's execution time.

here is the code

```js
function ulrFetch(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var class = ss.getRange(1, 5).getValue();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var urlList = ss.getRange(3, 8, lr-1).getValues();
  var length = urlList.length
  for (var i = 0;i<length;i++){
    var url = urlList[i];
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.toString());
    var result = response.getContentText();
    var index = result.indexOf(class);
    if (index > -1){
      
      ss.getRange(i+3, 5).setValue('1');
    }
    else {
      ss.getRange(i+3, 5).setValue('0');
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Can I ask you about the value of ``length`` of ``var length = urlList.length``? I think that in your situation, you can use [fetchAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)). fetchAll() can be worked by the asynchronous processing. But because also I think that when ``length`` is large, it might not be able to use it.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your response and length of urlList is 720

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer, because I thought that 720 requests might be able to be used by fetchAll(). Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? I thought that 720 requests might be able to be used by fetchAll(). So I would like to propose to use fetchAll(). The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Create requests using `urlList`.
2. Retrieve values from URL using fetchAll().
3. Create values for putting to Spreadsheet.
4. Put the created values to "E3:E".

#### Modified script :

Please modify as follows.

From :

```
var urlList = ss.getRange(3, 8, lr-1).getValues();
```

To :

```
var urlList = ss.getRange(3, 8, lr - 1 - 1).getValues();
```

By this modification, the values from row 3 to last row can be retrieved.

And

From :

```
for (var i = 0;i<length;i++){
  var url = urlList[i];
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url.toString());
  var result = response.getContentText();
  var index = result.indexOf(class);
  if (index > -1){

    ss.getRange(i+3, 5).setValue('1');
  }
  else {
    ss.getRange(i+3, 5).setValue('0');
  }
}
```

To :

```
var requests = urlList.map(function(e) {return {url: e[0]}});
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
var values = res.map(function(e) {return e.getContentText().indexOf(class) > -1 ? ["1"] : ["0"]});
ss.getRange(3, 5, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
```

#### Note :

- If an error due to the limitation of fetchAll() occurs, please tell me. I would like to modify the script.

#### Reference :

- [fetchAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi thank you for providing answer seems convincing but i am getting this error  "Invalid argument: http:// " on this line "var res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests); "

Comment: @Ace Cool I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. In this modified script, ``urlList`` is 2 dimensional array including URLs. The error occurs when the URL cannot be used. So can you provide sample URLs you want to use? I confirmed that in my environment, when the URL which can be used is used to requests, it works.

Comment: Perfect! it worked thank you so much for your time and support accepted your answer. :)

Comment: @Ace Cool I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.