# Slow MailApp.send in Google Sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-email

I have been using this mailapp coding for a while, and only sends to a list of people based on the EMAIL_SENT in column K, confirming it was sent in column J.  The list is long, but only sends to maybe 20 people per run based on the rule for column K (a formula sending to people actually working today).  Has worked great in the past.

Now though after recently reformatting the Google Sheet for my group, it takes 20-30 seconds to send one email off, and doesn't even finish the list of 20 emails in the 6 minute time limit.  My recent reformatting does include a lot more scripting on the Google Sheet overall with more Conditional Formatting, but not on the sheet that feeds this Script.

Any ideas what is slowing it down so much?

Thanks

```
function MorningEmail() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('EarlyEmail');
var startRow = 4;  
var numRows = 180;  
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 50)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
var fromName = row[16];
var replyToaddress = row[15];
var message = row[20]+row[21]+row[22]+row[23]+row[24]+row[25]+row[26]+row[27]+row[28]+row[29]+row[30]+row[31]+row[32]+row[33]+row[34]+row[35]+row[36]+row[37]+row[38]+row[39]+row[40]+row[41]+row[42]+row[43]+row[44]+row[45]+row[46]+row[47]+row[48]+row[49];       
var emailSent = row[10];     
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  
  var subject = row[19];
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    name: fromName,
    replyTo: replyToaddress,
    htmlBody: message
  });
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 10).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, ahead of my script I do have this to validate EMAIL_SENT. Didn't copy high enough on my script.

var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

Comment: I'm not sure the reason of the slow speed because I have never experienced the same situation. I'm sorry for this situation. So how about this modification of your script? Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, how about sending the emails by the fetchAll method of [the class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) using Gmail API? The fetchAll method works as the asynchronous process. So the process speed might become faster than the current situation.

Comment: Thanks for this Tanaike.  I've never used the UrlFetchApp.  Do you have any script I could see as an example of how this functions?  Thanks

Comment: Is this information useful for you? This is a sample script. This thread is for reducing the process cost using ``UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()``. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796140/reducing-execution-time-of-urlfetch-in-google-appscripts/51797202#51797202