# Error Showing in Simple Google Apps Script, How to hide

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple Google Apps Script that checks URLs, however, I would like to display something like "Not valid" for any non-200 status responses. Everything I try shows "#ERROR!" on the Google Sheet except for status 200 responses.

Here is my code:

```
function check_url(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  if( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
    return true
  } else if( response.getResponseCode() == 401 ) {
    return "401"
  } else {
    return "Not Valid"
  }  
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am not very familiar with GA scripts or Javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where you need a try catch block.  The fetch is throwing an error so there is no response.

```
function check_url(url) {
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
    if( response.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
      return true
    } else if( response.getResponseCode() == 401 ) {
      return "401"
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    return "Not Valid"
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should [`muteHTTPExceptions`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)):

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{'muteHTTPExceptions':true})
```

Also use arrays with [`fetchAll` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51797202), if you have a large number of urls to fetch.

Comment: I would love to use fetchAll as I have many, many URLs to check, but I can't figure out how to get all the URL list as an array. Sorry, I am just learning this stuff.