# can I increase the processing speed of UrlFetchApp.fetch() in a loop

Tags: performance, optimization, google-apps-script, google-apps, urlfetch

2I have an online web form and I am using google sheet to make mass submissions.

The code works fine for a couple of records but when I add 1000 - 2000 records, I see the processing time is really long and it takes a very long time for script to running and finish. It eventually times out.

Is there any way i can increase the speed by updating the code?

Currently, for each email address, the loop is running and i think that is causing the issue.

Here is my current code:

```
     //sheet refers to the sheet that includes email list (email list includes "Email" as a column header
    //paramValueSheet refers to the sheet that includes parameters values

var SENT_TAG = 'SEND_CONFIRMED';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('EmailAddressSheet');
var paramValueSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ParameterValuesSheet');

    function myFunction() {

    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process 
    var getlastrow_emailList =   sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
    var numRows = getlastrow_emailList; // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);

     // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
       var data = dataRange.getValues();

        var value1 = paramValueSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
        var value2 = paramValueSheet.getRange("A2").getValue();


    //  for (i in data) {   
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
          var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column 
        var emailSent = row[1]; // Second column


       if (emailSent != SEND_CONFIRMED) { // Prevents sending duplicates  

         var url = "https://www.SiteNameGoesHere.com/form?id=123456"; 
        UrlFetchApp.fetch(url +'&EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + '&PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));

           sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 2).setValue(SENT_TAG);
          // Flush to make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
       } 

      }

    //form submission
     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.FORM_URL_HERE.com/form?process=submit");

    }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

In order to implement `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()` to optimize the process, below is the updated code that I am using:

```
  //sheet refers to the sheet that includes email list (email list includes "Email" as a column header
    //paramValueSheet refers to the sheet that includes parameters values

var SENT_TAG = 'SEND_CONFIRMED';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('EmailAddressSheet');
var paramValueSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('ParameterValuesSheet');

    function myFunction() {

    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process 
    var getlastrow_emailList =   sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
    var numRows = getlastrow_emailList; // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);

     // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
       var data = dataRange.getValues();

        var value1 = paramValueSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
        var value2 = paramValueSheet.getRange("A2").getValue();

        var rqs = [];
        var ranges = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
          var row = data[i];
          var emailAddress = row[0];
          var emailSent = row[1];
          if (emailSent != SEND_CONFIRMED) {  // Should SEND_CONFIRMED be "SEND_CONFIRMED" or SENT_TAG?
            var url = "https://www.SiteNameGoesHere.com/form?id=123456"; 
            var req = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url +'&EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + '&PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));
            SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(req);
            rqs.push(req);
            ranges.push("B" + (startRow + i)); // Modified
          }
        }
        UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(rqs);
        sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(SENT_TAG); // Modified
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();



    }
```

This updated code is throwing the following error:

`"bad value"` **on line UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(rqs);**

To troubleshoot the issue, you can see I have added an alert in this updated code:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(req);
```

The alert window is showing me value like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" class="no-js" data-reactroot=""><head><meta..so on..
```

which tells me that code is hitting the form page and page is being rendered, the `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(rqs);` is what causing the issue here.

**UPDATE 2:**

For testing purpose, I have tried updating the following line in the UPDATE 1 code's loop:

```
var req = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url +'&EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + '&PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));
```

**to this:**

```
var req = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url +'&EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + '&PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));
```

*Basically using getRequest()

In this case, the alert window `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(req);`
shows me this value `[object Object]`

And this time error is coming on this new updated line:

```
var req = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url +'&EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + '&PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));
```

Error says:

```
Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:X-Forwarded-For
```

The execution of the script is not even reaching `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(rqs);` like in Update 1.

I really hope this makes sense and if I can get some help?

Comment: Yes. *Make* the request in a loop. *Execute* the requests all at once. Well, at least in a larger batch size... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object) Also consider that you don't need to `flush` unless you **require** that all pending spreadsheet writes be serialized before your next spreadsheet read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reducing Execution time of UrlFetch in google AppScripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796140/reducing-execution-time-of-urlfetch-in-google-appscripts)

Comment: Hi @tehhowch thanks for your response. If you see my code, I am already making requests in a loop then submitting it at once. Could you please clarify what you mean? Also, I am doing "flush" because I am writing some values in cells in a loop for each email which I have not included here. Flush makes sure that cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted.

Comment: @kuml no, you are both creating *and* executing the request within a loop. Did you bother looking at the link I gave?

Comment: Hi @tehhowch yes I did and the link includes an example with json which is a  different approach from mine. Yes, I am building the URL with form link within the loop but submission is being done once after the loop where I have "var response". Could you please clarify in the code, what exactly you mean? May be I am not understanding as I am new to this. Thank you

Comment: I think you are referring to this? `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(request1, request2);` request is being sent once only? Thanks @tehhowch for your help

Comment: @kuml Can I ask you about your script? In your script, I thought that the query parameter of ``https://www.FORM_URL_HERE.com&EMAIL=...`` is required to be ``https://www.FORM_URL_HERE.com?EMAIL=...``. And where are ``emailvalue``, ``value1`` and ``value2`` declared? ``emailAddress`` in the for loop is not used. So the value of ``url`` is not changed in the for loop. How about these? If you can do, please update your script. By this, it will help users think of about your issue.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike I agree with you. I have posted the complete function code above. I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you

Comment: @kuml Thank you for replying and updating your question. In your updated script, the URL which is requested is not changed in the for loop. I think that ``emailAddress`` is not used in URL. I thought that you might make a mistake writing it. So can you update it? I would like to modify the script by correctly understanding it. By the way, can I ask you about the reason that you use ``SpreadsheetApp.flush()``? If I misunderstood your script, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thank you for pointing that out. You are right, I did make a mistake in posting the code here. I have updated the code again (above ^) and now you can see the "emailAddress" is being passed in the URL.

Comment: Hi @tehhowch I have been looking into fetchAll(Object) and it looks like it is the way too go in this case. Just having difficulty understanding how to update my approach to use fetchAll(Object).

Comment: `rqs.push(UrlFetchApp.getRequest(...)); ... } UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(rqs);`. Very simple

Comment: Hi @tehhowch thank you for your response. I am fairly new to this so I would appreciate if you could please elaborate this in regard to my use-case?

Comment: @tehhowch what part of my code should replace this? could you please explain so I understand the approach?

Comment: Between the documentation link in the first comment, the suggested duplicate link, and my most recent code snippet hint, what is unclear? Think about what you are doing, then review the suggested duplicate and think about what it is doing. You might learn some new functions while studying that answer. That's ok. Your solution is in that other answer. Your task is to just translate the procedure into your specific situation.

Comment: Hi tehhowch & @Tanaike I am having difficulty in translating my approach to fetchAll since I am not understanding how to run a look for each email address while  in the given examples the value of URL is static. In my example, I am constructing the url with all the params. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @kuml Thank you for replying and updating it. From your updated script and your comments, I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that didn't work. I apologize. At that time, can you provide the detail information?

Comment: Do not "move the goal posts" by editing your question to ask about a new error. If you have a new specific issue, ask a new question, complete with necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the URL is declared as `url +'EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + 'PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2)`. In this case, it becomes as follows.

  - `https://www.FORM_URL_HERE.com/form?&EMAIL={emailAddress}PARAM1={value1}&PARAM2={value2}`
  - In this modification, this is modified as follows.
  - `https://www.FORM_URL_HERE.com/form?EMAIL={emailAddress}&PARAM1={value1}&PARAM2={value2}`
- `setValue()` is used at outside of the for loop. By this, the process cost can be reduced.
- In this modification, `rqs.push(UrlFetchApp.getRequest(...)); ... }` [proposed by tehhowch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002614/can-i-increase-the-processing-speed-of-urlfetchapp-fetch-in-a-loop?noredirect=1#comment96799560_55002614) was used for creating the request object for the fetchAll method.

#### Modified script:

Please replace your for loop `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {...}` to the following script and try again.

```
var rqs = [];
var ranges = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var row = data[i];
  var emailAddress = row[0];
  var emailSent = row[1];
  if (emailSent != SEND_CONFIRMED) {  // Should SEND_CONFIRMED be "SEND_CONFIRMED" or SENT_TAG?
    var url = "https://www.FORM_URL_HERE.com/form?";
    var req = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url +'EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + '&PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));
    rqs.push(req);
    ranges.push("B" + (startRow + i)); // Modified
  }
}
UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(rqs);
sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(SENT_TAG); // Modified
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

#### Note:

- In your script, `paramValueSheet`, `SEND_CONFIRMED` of `if (emailSent != SEND_CONFIRMED) {` and `AudienceList` are not declared. Although I thought that those might be declared at elsewhere, please confirm them again.
- About `SEND_CONFIRMED` of `if (emailSent != SEND_CONFIRMED) {`, should `SEND_CONFIRMED` be `"SEND_CONFIRMED"` or `SENT_TAG`?

#### References:

- [getRequest(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl)
- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangelista1notations)

I'm not sure about the specification of API you are using. And in my environment, also I'm not sure whether the request to the endpoint works. About this, please confirm in your environment. I apologize for this situation.

### Edit 1:

From your comment, it was found that the following script worked.

```
var url = "https://www.FORM_URL_HERE.com/form?";
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url +'&EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + 'PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));
```

In this case, the URL is as follows.

```
https://www.FORM_URL_HERE.com/form?&EMAIL={emailAddress}PARAM1={value1}&PARAM2={value2}
```

If this is reflected to the modified script, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var req = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url +'EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + '&PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));
```

To:

```
var req = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url +'&EMAIL=' + encodeURIComponent(emailAddress) + 'PARAM1=' + encodeURIComponent(value1) + '&PARAM2=' + encodeURIComponent(value2));
```

If this modification didn't work, please confirm all values of `emailAddress`, `value1` and `value2`. And also, it might be required to consider the limitation of the number of simultaneous accesses of webform.

### Edit 2:

If you want to request the URL by splitting the requests, please modify above script to the following script.

#### From:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(rqs);
```

#### To:

```
var numberInRequest = 100; // Number of URLs requested in one request.
var loop = Math.ceil(reqs.length / numberInRequest);
for (var i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
  UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(rqs.splice(0, numberInRequest)); Modified
}
```

- Here, if you want to request every 100 requests, please set `numberInRequest` to 100.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189636/discussion-on-answer-by-tanaike-can-i-increase-the-processing-speed-of-urlfetcha).